# How to reuse a duplicated (merged) pull request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I created two pull requests [#15](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/ZMC/pull/15) and [#17](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/ZMC/pull/17) which contained identical commits. Since the commits contained identical files, I closed pull request #17 and request #15 was merged into the upstream repository [HPQC/ZMC](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/ZMC/). I would now like to reopen PR #17, so that I can use it to push remaining commits to the upstream repo. This is important because then each PR would correspond to the addition of additional files important for the project.

When trying to reopen the pull request I received an error message indicating that the commits have already been merged (see below). Thus, I tried reverting my repository to a commit before these changes though I still received the same error. Is there a workaround for this situation?

[image]

Comment: +1 Currently your Pull Request #17 does have commits which are already merged into the upstream fork, so the error message that says "These commits are already merged" seems very accurate. You said "I've also tried reverting my repository to a commit before these changes", but the current version of your Pull Request still has 8 commits that are "already merged". If you really do synchronize the branch (sichaox:main) associated with your Pull Request, the error message would no longer make sense, so I doubt that you would see that error message again. Can you try that and show us the result?

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of making new commits on top of the existing (merged) commits, then pushing the branch? I would expect that at this point you are permitted to re-open #17 because there are new commits.

Comment: @j6t New commits have indeed been made on top of the existing commits, but none of them are being registered Pull Request #17 (Just look at the main branch sichaox:main and the Pull Request #17 and you'll see that none of the new commits are showing up, and the commits that are currently being shown for Pull Request #17 have been reverted in sichaox:main). The problem seems to be that closed pull requests don't update when new commits are pushed (is that true?) and GitHub isn't allowing the PR to become "open" either.